# How to make button unclickable after it is being clicked?

Tags: jquery

I want that after my button is clicked, it would be unclickable for a few seconds, how can I do it? I want to write a code for all buttons, not just for a one. So, I need something like that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        $(this).css("hidden: true");
        delay(3);
        $(this).css("hidden: normal");
    })    
})
```

It is just a pseudo-code, could you give me a hand?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        var input = this;
        input.disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
           input.disabled = false;
        }, 3000);

    });    
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ya5v7/).

Without jQuery...

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {      
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type="button"]')
    .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let input = e.target;
        input.disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
           input.disabled = false;
        }, 3000);

    });    
});
```

Alternatively capture the clicks on a persistent ancestor element and check if they're `input[type="button"]` types. This prevents attaching multiple events for each element.

Comment: `this` is going to have the wrong context in the anonymous function, and thus this won't work

Answer (score 6):

Add the disabled attribute.

```
$(this).attr('disabled', true);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, though it seems not to be answering the question. ;) thx

Answer (score 4):

Disabling an element is done by adding the `disabled` attribute, giving it the value `disabled`. Enabling it again is done by removing the attribute.

**Update:** Fixed the answer by using `setTimeout` -- sorry for the confusion with `$.delay`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        setTimeout(function() { el.removeAttr('disabled'); }, 3000);
    })    
})
```

Comment: This [wouldn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/5287e/) for me, did I do something wrong? I was under the impression `delay()` worked for effects queues only.

Comment: @alex - that's correct, you need to use setTimeout, see below

Comment: @ezmilhouse: I don't understand, why Jon's example doesn't work?

Comment: @alex: Turns out `delay` doesn't work for all methods. I corrected the answer, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: you can use delay only on functions that are part of jquery's effect queue. attr/removeAttr are not part of it. Here are all functions that can make use of delay: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        $(this).hide().delay(3000).show();
    })    
})
```

Comment: Beware that this only hides the element instead of making it unclickable

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/ezmilhouse/Hw6Gf/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    $('input[type="button"]').click(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
        setTimeout(function() {
           $('input[type="button"]').removeAttr('disabled');
        }, 3000);

    });    
});
```